# Inserting and printing elements of a list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So basically in the code below I am trying to create a list which contains some names and ages. I don't receive any errors or warnings but it doesn't print anything. What I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
   to create the 'people' array 
*/

#define HOW_MANY 7
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
              "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

typedef struct person
{
  char *name;
  int age;
  struct person *next;
}Person;


static void insert(Person *p, char *name, int age) 
{
  Person *headp = NULL;
  p = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person)); 
  if (p == NULL)
    abort();
  p->name = name;
  p->age = age;
  p->next = headp;
  headp = p;
}  

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

  Person *people=NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
  {
    insert (people, names[i], ages[i]);
  }

  while (people != NULL)
  {
    printf ("name: %s, age: %i\n", people->name, people->age);
    people = people->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to `p` inside the function does not change `people` from main, which is why you should find `people` to still be `NULL` when you go about printing.

You could return the new value for `p` from `insert` and assign that value to `people`.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? What type should the function insert be?

Comment: If it is returning the value in `p`, it would be the same type as `p`.